# Are ores replenished over time?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In previous games, the amount of minerals found in a vein was set in stone.  Now that blacksmithing is a feature, will minerals regrow after a certain amount of time as plants do?

Comment: On a similar note does "everything" regenerate like oblivion did? Meaning you can go back to the same mine you searched days ago and fine more goodies? I hope so, that's what made oblivion the kind of game you could spend so m uch time on.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The official strategy guide mentions that ores grow back after about a month, so there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Point of interest: The Oblivion official strategy guide said that Flowers regrew after a month, when actually it was only 3 days. Any luck with a verifiable time till respawn?

Comment: @Raven Modders have already been able to partially inspect the ESM with existing Fallout 3 tools, and have confirmed that the cell reset is 30 days.

Comment: According to the UESP, it's only 30 days if the mine gets the "Cleared" Tag. for other places and overworld mining nodes, it looks to be only 10 days.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried it out, but it would seem that the amount of ores in a vein do regenerate after some time.

Given that Todd Howard claimed that Skyrim has an infinite number of quests, having a number set in stone for ores seems kind of counter-intuitive.

I'll mine some ore tonight and play around for a bit to see how long it takes to respawn exactly.

Answer (score 4):

I'm in steam-scorch mine near Kynesgrove right now and the malachite ore has regenerated.  But, the strange thing is that I am unable to mine them (the option does not even appear), it does not give me the option so it is probably a glitch of some kind.

The same thing has happened at Goldenrock Mine (by Darkwater Crossing), the ore has regenerated but I can't mine it.  Maybe it has not been long enough yet, or there is a glitch where it shows the ore to be there when it is actually still depleted.  Hopefully this glitch will fix itself so that I don't have to go tramping around looking for mines to get my smithing up to 100.  I want to see what the dragon smithed items are like.

Edit: Restarted the game and can now mine the ore that was replenished but not targetable.

Comment: The note [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Mining) suggests that it's just not done replenishing yet.

Comment: Untargetable ores can be mined by simply equipping a pickaxe as a one handed weapon and attacking the vein, usually. Dunno if that'd work in your situation though. :)

Answer (score 0):

The last time I played Skyrim, ore regenerated quite fast.

You could go into a mine

Mine all the ore

Leave the mine

Wait 2 or 3 days

Go back into the mine to check if it's respawned (it should have, if not then wait a couple more days)

Because of a persistent bug, you will likely have to leave the mine and then re-enter the mine before being able to mine the now respawned ore, or simply wait for the minimum amount of time (I forget which)

When the ore has visibly respawned and it's the first time going, you will notice that you don't clip with it and are unable to mine it. Going outside the mine, waiting for an hour and going back in was the way to deal with this if I remember correctly.